# How are rational exponents defined in groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group. How is $g^{n/m}$ defined for $n,m \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: What makes you think $g^{\frac{n}{m}}$ is defined at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it's defined as a solution of $(g^{n/m})^m=g^n$. But notice that this solution doesn't have to be unique. Consider for example $x^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$. Also, it doesn't have to exist. Consider for example $x^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$. Groups in which such solutions exist are known as divisible; uniqueness is satisfied for torsionfree groups.